# Import library Oshi

Tags: java, oshi

I would like to develop a program that shows the computer information.
I found a library called ["Oshi"](https://github.com/oshi/oshi). When I import this library and run my code, there is an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/Platform
at oshi.SystemInfo.<init>(SystemInfo.java:40)
at Main.main(Main.java:10)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jna.Platform
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 7 more
```

I would like run this code:

```
SystemInfo si = new SystemInfo();
OperatingSystem os = si.getOperatingSystem();
System.out.println(os);
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oshi has some dependencies you'll need to download and add to your classpath as well. Check out 
https://github.com/dblock/oshi/blob/master/pom.xml

Inside check  and download the mentioned jars (from maven central maybe)

Answer (score 2):

I'm one of the main developers for Oshi.  As @Jan says, you need some dependencies.  Specifically you need [Java Native Access (JNA)](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) and a logging system that implements slf4j.

If you use build software that manages dependencies (highly recommended) clicking on the "Central Repository" link from the main README page will give you the appropriate code to put in your build script, and also give you an idea which versions of the jars you need if you are installing them manually.

Answer (score 0):

**You must add this libs:**
[jna-5.1.0.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/5.1.0/jna-5.1.0.jar) 
 
[jna-platform-5.1.0.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna-platform/5.1.0/jna-platform-5.1.0.jar) 
[slf4j](https://www.slf4j.org/dist/slf4j-1.7.25.zip) use only **slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar** and **slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar**

Comment: Do not provide links as an answer because they can be corrupted over time.

Comment: Why should one download these files by hand?