# NoClassDefFoundError thrown when trying to use get() methods from OSHI

Tags: java, oshi

I'm using OSHI (Operating System Hardware Information), a java project, intended to obtain system information.

I'm using NetBeans IDE and have added the individual jar files for each of the dependencies to the project library. But whenever I try to use any of the get() methods, a NoClassDefFoundError is thrown. For example, this is my code where I try to get the OS information (I've added all the necessary import statements);

```
SystemInfo si=new SystemInfo();
HardwareAbstractionLayer hal = si.getHardware();
Sensors sense=hal.getSensors();
System.out.println("Cpu Temperature" + sense.getCpuTemperature());
```

When I run this code, it shows the following error;

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Variant$VARIANT
at oshi.hardware.platform.windows.WindowsSensors.getCpuTemperature(WindowsSensors.java:54)
at pandorastress.PandoraUI.b1ActionPerformed(PandoraUI.java:168)
at pandorastress.PandoraUI.access$000(PandoraUI.java:55)
at pandorastress.PandoraUI$1.actionPerformed(PandoraUI.java:83)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Variant$VARIANT
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 40 more
```

is there any way to rectify this?

Comment: Can you try a clean/build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [some previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34061103/import-library-oshi?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), you need Java Native Access (JNA) library and a logging system that implements slf4j.

To add the JNA support you can download the appropriate (based on your system) bundle from this [link](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/tree/master/lib/native).

Also, you can try to add the JNA-bundle directly by [downloading the jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna) and adding it to your project.

Otherwise, you can change your project to a maven project and then use the maven to build your project. This will download all the dependencies.

Comment: Doesn't work. If I use the platform library, it shows "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/Platform
 at oshi.SystemInfo.<clinit>(SystemInfo.java:59)..." and if I use jna-3.3.0.jar, it shows the same error as in the question! :( @Andrei

Comment: Updated my answer, try to add the JNA bundle to your project.

Comment: I've already downloaded all the jar files of the dependencies mentioned in the OSHI page (Jna-4.5.1, slf4j, threetenbp-1.3.6) and added them to my project. Yet, the error doesn't resolve.

Comment: Try the Maven approach if it is possible. Make sure you add the correct jna bundle. There are different versions depending on the OS. Check out the second link.

Comment: Yeah, Maven downloaded both JNA and Jna-platform dependencies, and now I get the output! However, it shows 0.0, but I think it is because my computer doesn't support OSHI! Thanks!